# Setting up static routes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dynamic, routes, match

Need some Rails help (using rails 4.0.8 and ruby 2.0.0)...

I'm trying to refactor my routes, so instead of having...

```
App::Application.routes.draw.do
   get "static_pages/home"
   get "static_pages/help"
   get "static_pages/about"
   get "static_pages/contact"
end
```

.. in my routes fI'm setting it to be....

```
App::Application.routes.draw.do
   root 'static_pages#home'
   match '/help', to: 'static_pages#help', via: 'get'
   match '/about', to: 'static_pages#about', via: 'get'
   match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact', via: 'get'
end
```

...But when I do this, I thought that "match '/about' " is supposed to automatically create named routes for use in controllers and views that looks like...

```
about_path -> '/about'
about_url -> 'http://localhost:3000/about'
```

...but it doesn't do so in my controller. So I figured, "Okay, I'll manually put them in", and so I made app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb...

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
   def home
      root_path -> '/'
      root_url -> 'http://localhost:3000/'
   end

   def help
      help_path -> '/help'
      help_url -> 'http://localhost:3000/help'
   end

   def about
      about_path -> '/about'
      about_url -> 'http://localhost:3000/about'
   end

   def contact
      contact_path -> '/contact'
      contact_url -> 'http://localhost:3000/contact'
   end
end
```

...which doesn't do anything. So now when I try to go to the home page, for example, I get the routing error **No route matches [GET] "/static_pages/home"**.

I'm new to rails development so I'm sure there's something fairly obvious I'm missing here. Can anyone shed some light on what's going on? Much appreciated.

**EDIT 1 WITH ANSWER**

The answer was given by BroiSatse and Ako...

In the routes config I was mising the as: key, so updating my code to

```
App::Application.routes.draw.do
  root 'static_pages#home'
  match '/help', to: 'static_pages#help', via: 'get', as: :help
  match '/about', to: 'static_pages#about', via: 'get', as: :about
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact', via: 'get', as: :contact
end
```

Did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: This is not dynamic routes. These are static routes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you're missing is `as` key:

```
App::Application.routes.draw.do
  root 'static_pages#home'
  match '/help', to: 'static_pages#help', via: 'get', as: :help
  match '/about', to: 'static_pages#about', via: 'get', as: :about
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact', via: 'get', as: :contact
end
```

Adding as key will make the routes named and will create required url_helpers.

EDIT:

However, you can do much better:

```
App::Application.routes.draw.do
  root 'static_pages#home'

  scope controller: :static_pages do
    get :help
    get :about
    get :contact
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To define your named routes you can do this:

```
match '/about', to: 'static_pages#about', via: 'get', as: :about
```

This will give you `about_path`.

You can find out more about naming routes [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes).